# Do the characters in the Disney Hercules Movie know the Muses talk?

Tags: plot-explanation, hercules-1997

It sort of seems that they look their direction or "sing along" but I don't think they're fully acknowledged. Are they actually singing and narrating in-universe? Or is it like in some musicals where the musical part doesn't actually happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters do not directly communicate with the muses, so I think they're talking and singing just like in musicals, and it's not actually happening in real.